# Redis XGROUP DELCONSUMER . What happens with the pending messages?

Tags: redis

Can they be reassigned, put back onto the queue?

What good way is there to ensure nothing pending is there for too long?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `xpending` command:

```
XPENDING mystream group55 - + 10 consumer-123
```

Comment: What does this do exactly?

Comment: it returns 10 first pending messages  from `mystream` stream for whose owner is `consumer-123` in consumer group `group55` and then you can use `xclaim` to take ownership and process such messages.

Comment: Ok, yes I do that now already. I get this list and then put them back on the "queue" / stream, and then remove the consumer. Preferably I would like to do that in one safe transaction. All or nothing. I am doing this using Redisson. This what I have in Java: https://imgur.com/a/VFiwOkH

Comment: Your code is messy.  You call `removeConsumer` on `id` which looks like message id and on `claimingConsumer` but you call `claim` on that consumer and not it's the owner of pending messages. I'd suggest to  read redis docs for `xpending` and `xclaim` command to understand how they work.

Comment: Id is consumerId as a parameter coming in. I only use the claiminConsumer to transfer them before deleting the consumer by id. Then I remove the claimaint as well, and then since I have the messages already prior, I put them back on the queue. Question is wether that transaction stuff has any effect. I dont know. Documentation is so basic it provides no real info on various options. Nor any real world scenarios to mimic real queues or built in functionality to handle non handled messages due to failover.

Comment: The reason I get the pending and then claim them is because of another topic listener might be trying to do the same. Claim command ensures only one gets claimed.

Comment: when you make `removeConsumer` all his messages are removed from PEL and marked as `ack` so you just lose them. So you should find all pending messages for consumer by `xpending` then take the ownership by `claim`, process all these messages and only then you can remove old consumer.

Comment: i am doing that, they are removed, but the original messages in the java version is already retrieved and I add them back. They won't be associated with the old ones however. The problem of claiming ownership is that they just become pending in the new claimant, correct? What do I do with them in the pending queue of an active consumer? They are not pending there since said consumer is not working on them, they need to end up on the queue again I feel, otherwise consumer which already have pending himself, will need to work move those in their pending to a real pending.

Comment: The only sensible thing to do is not to move them to the pending state of another consumer. What do I do with them there? He needs them to work on them, and not just him, anyone could work them. Putting them on queue is the only thing that makes sense really.

Comment: It doesnt really make sense to move pending from one consumer to another consumers pending. What makes sense would be to move them to the front of the queue. Ideally a timeout setting for a message to do that automatically would have been great. If a message has not been acked in X seconds or if consumer is dead it is automatically moved to the front of the queue again.

Comment: Streams aren't queue they are logs. If you need a queue then you can use `Lists`. Or look to Kafka which can re-arrange client consumers.

Comment: I have tried Lists as well, however, they do not support tracking pending, nor acking ( although that is not required), albeit I could possibly do that myself, but it was suggested to me that I use Streams since they included the ability to track pending ones. The problem is keeping track of taken list items (queue) and if a server dies after taking one but not worked them then those items needs to go back on queue. I could however possibly have tracked those pending myself which might have saved me some headache. But it included two operations which I wasn't sure I could do transactionally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220583/discussion-between-max-grigoriev-and-mmm).

Comment: One take from list, and one add to pending. Then remove from pending on success, or put back in queue. A processing might also be successfull but a remove from pending remain.

Answer (score 0):

**What happens with the pending messages when the consumer is deleted?**

According to [XGROUP DELCONSUMER](https://redis.io/commands/xgroup-delconsumer/), all pending messages will be ***deleted***.
You can easily verify it by yourself:

```
// Create stream and fill it with some messages
XADD mystream * msg 1
XADD mystream * msg 2
XADD mystream * msg 3

// Create group for stream and set read position to start
XGROUP CREATE mystream mygroup 0

// Read 2 messages
XREADGROUP GROUP mygroup myconsumer COUNT 2 STREAMS mystream >

// Verify that messages we read are pending
XPENDING mystream mygroup - + 10 myconsumer

// Delete Consumer
XGROUP DELCONSUMER mystream mygroup myconsumer

// Verify that pending messages are gone
XPENDING mystream mygroup - + 10 myconsumer

// Verify that new consumer receives third message only
XREADGROUP GROUP mygroup mynewconsumer STREAMS mystream >
```

AFAIK there is no explicit way to put pending messages back to stream, but you can reassign them with [XCLAIM](https://redis.io/commands/xclaim/) and [XAUTOCLAIM](https://redis.io/commands/xautoclaim/) to another consumer and then safely delete consumer.